# Python - repeat function after n seconds inputted by user

Tags: python, python-3.x

My task is to create a program, which will turn heater on if temperature in the house is less than 16°C or turning it off if it's  more than 16°C. I decided to make it a bit useful and import the timer. I want to know how is it possible to repeat function, which allows to turn heater on or off, after "n" time inputted by user.
My current code is:

```
import time
import random


def main():
    
    temp = random.randint(-15, 35)
    print("Current temperature in the house:", temp,"°C")
    time.sleep(1)

    if temp <= 16:
        print("It's cold in the house!")
        t = input("How long should the heating work? Enter time in 1.00 (hours.minutes) format:")
        print("Heating will work for:", t)
        print("House Heating status: ON")
        time.sleep() //The timer should start here for the time entered by the user
        
        
        
    if temp > 16 and temp <= 25:
        print("House Heating status: OFF")
    if temp => 26:
        print("House Cooler status: ON")


main()
```

Which technique should I use to add this timer?

Comment: You can just use a while true loop and then use `time.sleep(n)` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `main` function handles the call to `time.sleep` already, a simple way to repeat over and over would be to put your function in an infinite loop:

```py
while True:
    main()
```

Another way would be to have your `main` function return an integer of how long to wait until it should be called again. This decouples the waiting from the main logic.

```py
def main():
    ...
    t = input("How long should the heating work? Enter time in 1.00 (hours.minutes) format:")
    ...
    return int(t)

while True:
    wait_time = main()
    time.sleep(wait_time)
```